# how to seperate schema and resolvers and merage them apollo-server-express

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I have User and Post typeDefs/resolvers I want to separate them so I can get

```
User.schema.js 
User.resolver.js

Post.schema.js 
Post.resolver.js

link.Schema.js
link.resolvers.js
```

how to do this and merge them to get just one typeDefs/resolvers to pass it to

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been using the `merge-graphql-schemas` package for the type definition and lodash deep object merge function for the resolvers like so:

```
import merge from "lodash/merge"
import { mergeTypes } from "merge-graphql-schemas"
import UserSchema from "./User.schema"
import UserResolvers from "./User.resolvers"
import PostSchema from "./Post.schema"
import PostResolvers from "./Post.resolvers"
import LinkSchema from "./Link.schema"
import LinkResolvers from "./Link.resolvers"

const typeDefs = mergeTypes([UserSchema, PostSchema, LinkSchema])
const resolvers = merge(UserResolvers, PostResolvers, LinkResolvers)

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});
```

**EDIT:** please note that [`graphql-tools`'s `mergeSchemas`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-stitching.html) is now the recommended way of schema stitching with apollo server now.

Comment: cool thanks , I have one more question :
is it effect the code if I import gql several time to write schema ? or do you use another way to write schema 
const { gql } = require('apollo-server-express');

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    Users: [User]
    getUserById(id: ID): User
  }
  type User {
    id: ID
    name: String
    Post: [Post]
  }
  type Mutation
`;
module.exports = typeDefs;

Comment: What do you mean by "write schema"?

Comment: its about the size of file when I import gql from apollo-server 
dose that effect the application , dose that make the app bigger (size)
how do you write your schema ?
do you use gql api or do you make it string ?

Comment: I tend to always use the `gql` template literal from `graphql-tag`, but apollo server does accept both string and `gql` schemas. As for the other questions, they require answers that are too long to fit this comment :s

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for some more dependency for merging the types, as ***graphql-tools*** are fine for them.
Have a look https://github.com/techyaura/graphqlNodeMongodb-server/tree/master/src/gql, if it helps.

I have two files `todo.types.js` & `user.type.js` in the repo https://github.com/techyaura/graphqlNodeMongodb-server/tree/master/src/gql/types & I am simply concatenating them & that's working fine.

NOTE: I am not using ***APOLLO GRAPHQL***, instead using `express-graphql` simply